# Running Java Code from HTML5/Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have an app that is perfect for HTML5 except that it needs to execute some java code.  I have heard that javascript/html5 can execute java code and get results back but I'm not sure how this is done. Looking for an opensource library for this.  Does anyone know if/how this can be done? Please note I am building an HTML5 view but wrapped in a native Android app. So I want to access a Java library that is contained in the native android app from within Javascript.

Comment: A bit more context would be nice. You're developing a native Android app which uses javascript somewhere, correct? Are you using Titanium/PhoneGap/Nimble or something similar?

Comment: I am developing an HTML5 App which I am planning to wrap as native Android App.  So browser view will be included by native android app which will contain the java code.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into `addJavascriptInterface` for android

> Adding JavaScript-to-Java interfaces with the **addJavascriptInterface(Object, String)** method. This lets you bind Java objects into the WebView so they can be controlled from the web pages via JavaScript